# Inserting in line using sed command

Tags: linux, sed

The text in file looks like this:

```
 [homes]
            comment = Home Directories
            path = 
            browseable = 
            writable = yes
            valid users = %S
            valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = no
        guest ok = no
        writable = no
        printable = yes
```

I want output as:

```
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        path = /data
        browseable = yes
        writable = yes
        valid users = %S
        valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = no
        guest ok = no
        writable = no
        printable = yes
```

I am using this command:

```
sed -i "\#path# s#.*#& /data#" file
```

It makes changes to everywhere in file where path is located.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Rather than posting the same question again, please explain in your last question why the given solution does not work for you.

Comment: If there are other sections with empty `path =`, you probably want to apply to the `homes` section only: `sed '/\[homes/,/browsable/s#path =.*#path = /data#'`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the indention, this will do the job:

```
sed 's/ \{12\}/        /' file
```

It takes 12 sequent space characters (`\{12\}`) and replaces them by eight spaces.